# Creating a 'Favourites' section in an app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on an app in which I would like the users to be able to favourite a button and that button then gets added to the 'Favourites' section for that particular `ViewController`.

The app is a soundboard so it is split into (currently) 2 characters, within those characters I have categories of sound files for the users to choose from, once the user selects a category it will load up the `ViewController` with a set of sounds which can be played by pressing the button (very simple I know).

I'm trying to implement a 'Favourite' function in order to allow the user to favourite the buttons of their choice and in doing so, the new 'favourited' button will be displayed in a new `ViewController`.

I've browsed through here and found some stuff in regards to `NSUserDefaults`

I'm new to Swift and iOS development as a whole so if someone could be kind enough to guide me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

I know how to set the Image of the favourite button to change whether it has been set as a favourite or not, I also noticed that it suggests I place the favourites in a `UITableViewController`. My app is currently using a `UITabBarController` with 4 different `ViewControllers` off them.

If you would like screenshots of my Storyboard to get a better understanding please let me know and I shall update the post, also if any code is required please let me know and once again, I shall update the post!

*EDIT: I will happily add a button which when pressed loads a table view if someone knows how to add a normal button into a table view so when pressed it shows the favourites*

*EDIT 2: Image
[image: What i would like to happen]*

Comment: Please post some code you have tried it before, so it make clear what exactly you want. As I understand you want to make a favourite sound list and view this favourite list when user press favourite section?

Comment: check my update please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to do as follows-

1. Take a `UITabBarController` having one `viewController` as `soundsViewController` and another `tableViewController` as `favouritesTableViewController` shown as below image-

[image]

2. Now add these sample code to `soundsViewController`-

   ```
   var favListArray:NSMutableArray = []

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favList") != nil {

           favListArray = NSMutableArray.init(array: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favList") as! NSMutableArray)

       }

   }
   override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()

       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
       return 1
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
       return 10
   }



   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("soundCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

       cell.titleLbl.text = NSString.localizedStringWithFormat("Sound %d", indexPath.row) as String

       if favListArray.containsObject(cell.titleLbl.text!) {

           cell.addTOFVrtBtn.setTitle("-", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

       }else{

           cell.addTOFVrtBtn.setTitle("+", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
       }

       cell.addTOFVrtBtn.tag = indexPath.row

       cell.addTOFVrtBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(addToFav) , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

       return cell

   }

   func addToFav(sender:UIButton) {

       let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.init(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)) as! TableViewCell

       if favListArray.containsObject(cell.titleLbl.text!) {

           favListArray.removeObject(cell.titleLbl.text!)

       }else{

           favListArray.addObject(cell.titleLbl.text!)
       }

       tableView.reloadData()

       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(favListArray, forKey: "favList")

   }
   ```

these is a sample code, here `TableViewCell` is subclass of `UITableViewCell` having `titleLbl` and `addTOFvrtBtn`.

3. Add below sample code to `favouritesTableViewController` -

`varfavSoundList:NSMutableArray = []`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

super.viewWillAppear(animated)

if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favList") != nil {

favSoundList = NSMutableArray.init(array: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favList") as! NSMutableArray)

print(favSoundList)

self.tableView.reloadData()

}

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

    return 1

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return favSoundList.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = favSoundList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String

    return cell

}
```

Here is the o/p screen demo-

[image]

I hope this will help you or you can get an idea how to make Favourites list and Favourites section..Thanks

Comment: Bro In my code sound viewcontrollers is normal VC, in this I have added tableView from storyBoard.. and favourite view controller is UITableViewController..

Comment: Ok, For this give different tag value to each + btn and add common IBAction to all btn i.e addToFav and save sound name in array..

Comment: and use of tableView is very easy, You should try to use tableView for listing  because if your sound list increases than you don't have to add more button manually just reuse tableView cell..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118418/discussion-between-riosk-and-konsy).

Comment: so there are issues.. would you be able to return to the chat and resolve it?

Comment: Would you be able to help me with this, i know it's been a year haha but i've gone back to needing to do this? Would be very helpful, i can show what i have and how i need it to work if that's ok?

Comment: @Rohit Khandelwal how do you remove a cell from favorite with your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as favouriting a button, a button is just how you're displaying the data in your app - what you're really favouriting is the data itself, so in this case a particular sound file.

So, your current data is a list of sound files, or the path to those files. Your favourites list can be exactly the same. I imagine you might be simply getting a list of files from disk to display so your list of favourites will need to be stored differently. That could be in user defaults, or in a plist file, either way it's an array of strings and both are simple options to store the array.

When storing you just set the array into defaults with a key, or write it to a file. When you read back you should either read from user defaults and then make a `mutableCopy` or use `NSMutableArray` to read the file in so you have an editable instance afterwards and you can add and remove favourites from the list.

Your approach of using buttons to represent the sound files is probably a lot more code and effort than you require. Table views are specifically designed to show a list of things, and there's no reason that a table view can't look like a list of buttons (while being much more flexible and much less code to create).

Comment: how would i go about doing so? Please check my edit for more information!

Comment: so tapping the favourite button adds or removes the sound file path to the list (and updates the button UI). it wouldn't take you to another screen though. the table of favourites would be another tab in your tab controller probably.

Comment: To get to the favourites there would be a button saying Favourites which would then load the TableView. Does that make more sense?

Comment: the sound and '<3' would be two different buttons.

Comment: yes, and the `<3` button is to add/remove a sound as a favourite, not to show the list of favourites

Comment: yes correct, to show the menu there would be a button at the bottom saying 'Favourites' which loads the table view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118392/discussion-between-konsy-and-wain).